# Does Docker Hub put a big strain on package hosts?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, pypi, dockerhub

I've got a few Docker-based projects that all depend on each other:

- `project 1` depends on `python:3-alpine`
- `project 2` depends on `project 1`
- `project 3` depends on `project 1`

etc. etc.

As such, all of my automated builds are linked as above.  When I update project 2, projects 3 4 5 are all automatically rebuilt.  It's a pretty slick feature.

The thing is, this means that whenever a lower-level project is updated, this triggers lots of rebuilds of lots of projects.  In the case of something very low-level being updated, like `python` or `node`, I can imagine that Docker Hub is triggering a lot of rebuilds.

My question then is: doesn't this put a lot of load on package hosts like PyPI?  As each of my projects include a line something like:

`RUN pip install -r requirements.txt`

This hits PyPI to pull down all of the requirements, re-downloading each time without the ability to use a local cache because the Docker container is "brand new" for each build.

Is there something I can do to lessen the impact my projects are making, or is this somehow fixed with "magic" on Docker Hub?  In the absence of such magic, is there a Best Practise I should be following?

Answer (score 0):

After a successful build save cache directories somewhere outside docker in persistent storage. Restore the cache in every new container.

Comment: Do you have an example of a project doing this? How can this be done without tainting the trust involved in an automated build?

Comment: Any commercial CI (Continuous Integration) do that — I know Travis CI and AppVeyor. AFAIK Travis publishes their source code so you can try to lookup how do they do it.